# What is the learning curve for development on JD Edwards?

Tags: jdedwards

On an average, how much time does it take to become proficient in development using JD Edwards? Is it easy to learn? Are there any prerequisites?

Comment: We can if you provide us with your JDEDWARDS learning capability score. (its on page 5875241 of the manual of your brain).

Comment: Funny, but not particularly helpful or nice, Gamecat.

Comment: @sivaramakrishna You learned JDE ?

Answer (score 11):

I'm assuming you're interested on learning the development skills of JD Edwards, not the business processes that the system actually implements.

There are 2 versions of JDE. One runs over AS/400 plataforms, DB2 database and uses RPG (language) to implement reports and functionalities. I'm not acquainted with that version (did very few interface jobs and they were all complicated due to DB2's differences from my usual flavours of databases - Oracle or SQL Server).

The other version is EnterpriseOne (formerly OneWorld). I started developing for this version in 2000 and kept active until 2006. It's very easy to achieve the basic level of development and then you get to face the oddities and known issues from the system and how to dodge them and that's when you become experienced.

All development tools are internal to JDE. There's a table designer, a query designer (with a grid interface that resembles any visual query designer), an interactive programs designer (forms), a report designer and a business rules designer.

If you have experience with any RDA tool (like Visual Studio, for instance) and development for databases, you will be able to use this knowledge to ease the learning curve. In my case, I was a SQL programmer and I had a lot of experience with Visual Basic and Microsoft Access. I was able to use that experience by understanding the underlying concepts of the system and adapting for them. It took me about 25 hours of training with a more seasoned programmer to get me ready to at least do basic stuff on real customers. This amount of hours varies from person to person, obviously.

However, I can say that I only started to feel that I was understanding the tools and the process after 6 months of daily work on my first customer. After about 12-18 months, I was ashamed of the first applications that I wrote, so I actually went back and rewrote some on my own time... :-)

The thing about JDE is: there's very little coding/functionality on the database side (because it used to be flexible on databases choices). All the forms and reports are written inside the actual system by way of the designers.

All "coding" is done by way of a simple (and sometimes dumb) point-and-click interface. For instance: you don't write an assignment statement, like var = value. You select the Assignment button, then you select the variable in a list, then you select the value in a list (or enter the value, if it's fixed).

All the rules behind forms, reports and business rules are created that way. One exception: when you're writing a business rule, you can opt between using this approach (called Named Event Rule - NER) or using the C language (called Business Function).

If you choose NER, after you finish, the system actually converts that to C.

There are debug functionalities for forms, reports and business rules.

This is basic development. There are other tools and functionalities that are usually assigned to developers and so you will be able to do a lot more. I've worked a lot with interfaces, interoperability, workflow and more.

Also noteworthy is that JDE has an internal tool for managing objects, version control, checkins, checkouts and transfering objects from one environment to another to complete the development cicle.

As a developer, the more you learn about the business processes being implemented, the better. You get to learn the inside (code, specs) and outside (process) for the functionalities and this helps you as a developer and helps you in your career (and paygrade).

Now, my only caveat regarding my answer: as I've mentioned, it's been a while since I left JD Edwards development. As far as I know, things are pretty much the same, but I can't say for sure.

Best advice I can offer: go to www.jdelist.com for specific questions and help with issues. Be polite, try to ask questions about specific matters instead of general questions (I mean: if you ask those guys how long does it take to learn JDE, they will probably ignore you, but if you ask stuff like "in your opinion, what are the most complex tasks for a JDE developer to master?" you will probably get some pretty good answers).

Hope it helps and wish you good luck with JDE. After the initial bump, I enjoyed my ride on it quite a lot.

Comment: I am in the same situation. Thanks for your answer. And a +1 for giving info about jdelist.com

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the JD Edwards EntepriseOne Developer guide to learn about object management work bench, design tools for table, form and reports and API for Business Functions.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53430_01/nav/development.htm

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it depends on the version of JDE.  There are a lot of different components, and different versions (from what I can tell.)  For example, a sister company of ours is running JDE over terminals to an AS/400.  It's all "Green Screen" text-based screens, typing three letter commands at a command prompt, and using the cursor to move around the screen.

I haven't tried to learn it in depth yet, but trying to learn enough to do basic support has taken me several months at a few hours a week.  Think of JDE as a baby version of SAP, that gives you an idea of the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I taught some classes about JDEdwards EnterpriseOne Development.

One of my students who never programmed before took about 320 hours of trainning to be able to do some developments on JDEdwards. Nowadays he's a coworker and a good programmer.

His 320 hours of trainning was:

- During 5 months I taught on saturdays, 8 hours
- Then he got another trainning which was 4 hours week and 8 hours on saturdays for 5 weeks

As I've said after all this, he has being able to perform all tasks of a JDEdwards Developer.

And my advice to who is going to study this is to have a good knowledge of SQL and have programmed before in any compiled language, it helps a lot.