# Basics of Oracle JDE Development

Tags: .net, oracle, jdedwards

I am having experience of 2.6 years in Microsoft Technologies (Visual Studio 2008/2010, SQL Server 2008 etc). Well, I got an exciting job offer as JDE Programmer.
May I know the following,

1. Working of JDE ?
2. What are the important components of JDE ?
3. How can I migrate to JDE within few days?
4. Can I exercise JDE in my lap top, if so, where from I get installers
   of JDE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in the days, you could get a Standalone version of JDE Oneworld. It was a fully functional version of the software running in a single computer. The first versions used a MS Access database instead of the standard and then they've moved to SQL Server CE or Express.

But this was before the company was purchased by Peoplesoft and then Oracle. I don't know if they still have this Standalone version and what would be the requirements to run it.

You can probably get information at Oracle's JDE website, but I'm not sure if you will be able to download it (and if you are, brace yourself for several Gb of application).

I take it that you've seen my reply about learning JDE (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704131/how-many-days-does-it-take-to-learn-jdedwards/927206#927206). I still think that the information there is valid.

As far as I know, you will still be dealing with the same major components: Object Management Workbench (version control and development cycle), Table designer, Query designer, Data Dictionary, Application designer, Report designer and Business Rules designer.

JDE excels in terms of interoperability (importing/exporting data in different formats and technologies and interacting with different applications). A lot of work nowadays is on webservices and interoperability.

So, with a solid background in MS and if you have experience with webservices, you should be able to pick up the basics pretty quickly.

Best of luck to you.